# Shape creation on touch in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

In the app that I'm making, one part requires me to render an image from the server, and then have the ability to tap on it to have a box/rectangle form on it. Something like annotation. And once I'm done with that, either save coordinates of the boxes and send to the server, so send the image annotated with the boxes. What package/technique could I use to get that done? I have looked at sketch and other packages but they only seem to let me freehand draw... Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somehow vague question but React Native has some libraries to create shapes and forms. You need to check on ART and D3.

This is a nice read to start: http://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/

Comment: I recognize this might be your ifrst question, please make sure you accept the answers if you consider if solves your question so they don't go unsolved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll try this out and get back to you!